# Where can I find the HPI default configuration parameters?

Tags: gem5

I've been trying to find the default configuration parameters for the HPI cpu model in gem5 for a while now. I'm running a simple program on a very simple system and exporting the traces to run some DVFS optimization. Therefore I need to know exactly how many cycles the different instructions require, in order to calculate the CPU usage for a specific time interval. The cpu usage for the entire program is given in the stats file, but that will give me an unknown inaccuracy when taking fractions of the program, which I'm not very pleased with.

Therefore I ask, does anyone know where I can find the default configuration parameters of the HPI model, or by any chance know them and could list them? 
For clearification, how many CPU cycles per e.g IntAlu or IntMul?

Comment: I don't know this well, I should learn it, but have you looked into `configs/common/cores/arm/HPI.py`? Then e.g. there's some timing named stuff in there: `class HPI_IntFU(MinorFU):
    opClasses = minorMakeOpClassSet(['IntAlu'])
    # IMPORTANT! Keep the order below, add new entries *at the head*
    timings = [
` Then I'd follow the classes in that list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ciro, that helped a lot. I did some more digging and found out that the opLat truely is the instruction latencies. Although my numbers don't add up anyway, I atleast have that for certain. Have a great day